# Beginner VB 4x4 sudoku NumericUpDown checking values

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm creating a 4x4 Sudoku game which on load is completely empty and users fill numbers (1-4) and hit a button which confirms if the input is valid. The controls must be placed in the designer (not using code). When loading the input values into an array or list is there a shorter way then:

```
array[0] = nudC1R1
array[1] = nudC2R1 ...
```

something maybe like:

```
for (i=0;i<4;i++)
array[i] = nudc[i]r[x]
```

I realize that code is way wrong; just there to give you guys an idea of what I'm looking for.

Comment: have you considering putting the controls in an array?

Comment: actually, if you know the game is 4x4 you **can** place the controls at design time and simply store the **values** you want as an array;  you might even build a [Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/527aztek.aspx) which stores the data and either the related control name or maybe a control reference.

Comment: @ConradFrix that would involve a nearly identical set of steps wouldnt it?

Comment: @Plutonix storing the values that i want in array, rather then the values received(input) would do me no good since the values can be different (1,3,2,4 or 1,2,3,4). Even if I create a class, the class variables will need to be assigned to the arrays right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another way to do it, is to have two properties on your custom "cell" control (probably a textbox), row index and column index. Then in your `Sub New` after `InitializeComponent` place custom code to enumerate through all cells and build a dictionary, where key is `rowIndex|colIndex` for example `"0|1"`. Then, to populate your two-dimensional array, used for calculations (I am assuming that's what you will have in the end) just make a dual loop, something like this:

```
For i = 0 to 3
  For j = 0 To 3
    Dim key As String = i.ToString() & "|" & j.ToString()
    Dim cell As TextBox 'your custom type should go here instead
    If dict.TryGetValue(key, cell) Then
      array(i,j) = Convert.ToInt32(cell.Text)
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Comment: ah-ha! Makes since. I'll try this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx), although a little more verbose than your example:

```
Dim name = "nudC" & i & "R" & x
Dim friendFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance
Dim pi = Me.GetType().GetProperty(name, friendFlags)
Dim control As TextBox = pi.GetValue(Me)
array(i) = Int32.Parse(control.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it seems like you'd want to use the variable names when looping but as [Phillip Trelford answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23332848/119477) requires reflection. Also it isn't particularly safe. For example renaming a control will result in a run time error rather than a compile error.

Instead it would be better to declare a control map

```
Dim NupControls As New Dictionary(Of Integer, NumericUpDown)
```

Fill on Form_Load()

```
    Me.NupControls = New Dictionary(Of Integer, NumericUpDown) From
    {{1, Me.nudC2R1 },
     {2, Me.nudC2R1 }, 
     {3, Me.nudC2R1 }, 
     {4, Me.nudC2R1 }}
```

Then later when you go to populate your Array you just do

```
For Each i In NupControls.Keys
     array(i) = NupControls(i).Value
Next
```

or if you like Linq

```
  array = (From n In NupControls
           Order By n.Key
           Select n.Value.Value).ToArray()
```

or if you like Lambda expressions

```
  array = NupControls.OrderBy(Function(n) n.Key)
                     .Select(Function(n) n.Value.Value).ToArray()
```

Another option of course is to bind your controls to a data structure. That way you never need to collect the values

Comment: I spent some serious time reading about reflection. Although I didn't use this method thanks for the headache :P No, seriously, thanks you.